# How does Nx and Angular feature modules (routing) work?

Tags: angular, nrwl-nx

I'm confused about this, have searched it from yesterday.
Basically routing-module was not added by default and adding it from CLI makes some problems - cannot simply reroute after
click on a button with new route (although adding /sth in url works).
I am trying now to add shared lib with this module to my nx workspace. I've seen a lot of articles about creating my own schematics but it doesn't click in my mind.
Also Have seen on [github](https://github.com/ktrz/nx-photos) ([article](https://www.thisdot.co/blog/deploying-nx-workspace-based-angular-and-nestjs-apps-to-heroku)) and routing works there but don't know what's going on under the hood.

Comment: The answer is to import the router module from libs via import: `loadChildren: () => import('@libname/my-route').then((m) => m.My-Module)`.

Comment: The best resource on this kind of doubts which I've found is this: https://duncanhunter.gitbook.io/enterprise-angular-applications-with-ngrx-and-nx/